# Effects com jquery

Tags: jquery

Galera estou tendo uma dúvida, uso efeitos em jQuery assim:

```
$("#elemento").toggle(2000);
```

Dei uma olha na documentação mas não estou achando a forma correta de fazer isso, preciso de um evento onde começa da direita para esquerda. E com 'toggle' eu tenho esse efeito, porém a div começa do topo paras baixo também.

Bom quero aplicar esse efeito:
[Menu](http://www.maujor.com/tutorial/menu-maujor/menu-site-maujor5.html)

No menu que estou montando:
[Menu que estou montando](https://jsfiddle.net/q35xsopx/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi o problema assim:

```
$("#mySidenav").animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

Answer (score 3):

Seria isso que você quer:

```
$("#elemento").animate({left: "200px"}, 2000, function(){
        $(this).toggle();
        });
```

[Exemplo no JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fw2ckx6p/33/)

Comment: Bom não exatamente. Tentei dessa forma que vc falou, e não teve efeito nenhum, apenas criou uma margem de 200px. coloquei o link da menu que estou montando, poderia colocar seu código la, acho que estou fazendo algo errado. https://jsfiddle.net/q35xsopx/2/

Comment: Na hora de Exibir, quando passa o mouse em cima, fica acionando varias vezes o mesmo efeito

Comment: É porque estava como .mouseover. Agora mudei pra mouseenter e mouseleave.

Comment: o efeito e isso mesmo, poderia me ajudar a colocar ele nesse menu que estou montando? https://jsfiddle.net/q35xsopx/2/ Estou tentando colocar ele aqui mas não funciona

Comment: Assim que eu chegar em casa eu dou um jeito...

Comment: @JacksonAntunes ok fico aguardando, obrigado

Comment: @JacksonAntunes e ai deu uma olhada no menu?

Comment: Perdão Hugo, só cheguei hoje. Mas ainda bem que você conseguiu!

Answer (score 1):

Se tiver a possibilidade de usar bootstrap, faça dessa meneira.

```js
$( ".toggle-effect" ).click(function() {
  $( ".demo-toggle" ).toggle( "fast" );
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.toggle-effect {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.demo-toggle {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="toggle-effect">Clique Aqui</div>
<div class="demo-toggle">
  <p>Oi, eu sou seu toggle bem mais simples.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Oi, então eu não uso o bootstrap, e o efeito que eu quero e da direita para esquerda.

Comment: Pronto, editei o código.

Comment: Ainda não é o efeito que eu queria, ele tem que ir da direita para esquerda, editei a pergunta com o link do que eu quero fazer, e o que estou tentando fazer.